# FIWARE: IotAgent-json over MQTT

Tags: json, mqtt, fiware, fiware-orion

I'm working on connecting sensors to a **FIWARE** system.

The sensor can report the monitoring data **with MQTT in json payload**.
With a public mqtt broker(hivemq), I can get the monitoring data payload as below:
*{
"src":"shellyplus1pm-7c87ce64d540",
"dst":"shellyplus1pm-7c87ce64d540/events",
"method":"NotifyStatus",
"params":{
"ts":1659606613.35,
"switch:0":{
"id":0,
"apower":38.04
}
}
}*.

**my questions are**:

(1) the sensor can only publish data on topic ***DeviceId/events/rpc***, but if I use FIWARE IotAgent-json, the **IotAgent-json** expects subscribing data on topic ***/json/{{api-key}}/{{device-id}}/attrs*** (*according https://github.com/yanpengwuIoT/tutorials.IoT-over-MQTT*), how can I let the IotAgent-json subscribe data on topic ***DeviceId/events/rpc***, which is sensor firmware defined and can't be changed.

(2) the sensor publishs monitoring payload as a **nested multi-level json object** as showed above, but the IotAgent-json can only support a **single level json object** (*like '{"h": 70, "t": 15}' as described in https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/blob/master/docs/usermanual.md*), how can I parse the multi-level json object in IotAgent-json?

Any comment, sample or documentation for this are very appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small relay middleware to read from one topic and write to another:

```js
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const MQTT_BROKER_URL = process.env.MQTT_BROKER_URL || 'mqtt://mosquitto';
const MQTT_TOPIC_PROTOCOL = process.env.MQTT_TOPIC_PROTOCOL || 'json';

global.MQTT_CLIENT = mqtt.connect(MQTT_BROKER_URL);

MQTT_CLIENT.on('connect', () => {
    MQTT_CLIENT.subscribe('/+/events/rpc');
});
MQTT_CLIENT.on('message', measureReceived);



function measureReceived(topic, message) {
    const parts = topic.toString().split('/');
    // Extract the deviceId
    const deviceId = parts[2];
    // Muck around with the payload and use the right topic
    const apiKey = 'XXX'
    process.nextTick(() => {relay(apiKey, deviceId, newPayload, newTopic)});
}


function relay(apiKey, deviceId, state, topic) {
    let mqttTopic = '/' + apiKey + '/' + deviceId + '/' + topic;
    MQTT_CLIENT.publish(mqttTopic, state);
}
```

You could hard-code the logic to unpack the incoming complex measure and a create a simpler payload, or you could investigate the use of the IoT Agent's [expression library](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/expressionLanguage.html#expressions) and provision the device so that it cherry picks the correct parts of the payload. Doing this is more sustainable in the long run, but would require knowledge of the [JEXL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html) expression language

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and suggestions, it's much helpful and I will try it:).